# run postback only once with javascript

Tags: javascript, postback

I have to do a postback automatically when a user visit a page. How can I run this postback only once?

```
javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$ctr424$ViewLogin$btChange','')
```

Comment: Why are you posting back to the page immediately?  At first glance, this seems like an extra round-trip for your user that could be saved.

Answer (score 0):

If form_load register that as a startup script with the ScriptManager but only if not Page.IsPostBack.